# CORS error when receiving a response from server side code

Tags: javascript, server-side

Access to fetch at 'url' from origin 'url' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I have tried pretty much everything to try and get passed this error, but it is still appearing any ideas or tips we be very much appreciated.

Server side:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const DataStore = require('Nedb')

const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {  
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    next();
  });

const database = new DataStore('database.db');
database.loadDatabase();

app.use(cors());
    app.use(express.json());

app.post('/dbpostLoad', (req, res) => {
     database.find({}).exec(function (err, data){
        res.json(data)
     }); 
});
```

Client side:

```
window.addEventListener('load',(event)=> { 
    const options1 = {
        method : 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        }
    } 

    getData();
    async function getData(){
        const response = await fetch(loadData_URL, options1);
        const data = await response.json();
```

Comment: Have you tried the Chrome `Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin` extension? Mixed reviews but worked for me: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en

Comment: I did try this and it also did not work. I did not want to lean on that as well as I am planning on using this on a mobile device as well. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Server side:

```
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
app.use((req, res, next) => { 
  cors(req, res, () => {
       //Your code here
  })
});
```

Comment: I was also unable to get passed the error with this as well. More than happy to do a screen share session if it will help. I know not all of my code is here and it may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some error in API.

'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' should  e true in API.

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="content-type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

Comment: I could be missing something here, but this also did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with the code, the error might be in any other part of your codebase. If it is open source, sharing link of the repo might help.

#### Try tesing with `curl`

```
curl -i localhost:3001/dbpostLoad
```

#### Some tweaking that I would suggest

`app.use(cors())` will be the first statement after `const app = express();`. And you don't have to set that header manually.

The following part of code can be removed:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {  
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    next();
});
```

Comment: I will make those changes and test. I will also get a repo together in a little bit and add it. Thank you.

Comment: Here is the repo:  https://github.com/bkits2/comicapp  . I tested with curl and it failed. I also made the code changes mentioned. Thank you for taking a look. Also, go easy literally my first experience with full stack. I know my code needs cleaned up I was planning on doing so once I got this figured out.